# iOS/iPhone: Can you have only an english supported in-app purchase for an app distributed worldwide?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have an app that available for worldwide distribution.  It doesn't support localization at the moment, though maybe 5% of downloads come from countries where English is not the primary language (though, likely spoken and understood).

I just yesterday submitted an in-app purchase for the app that has its own tab on the primary tabViewController.  The tab is always there.  If a person has not purchased the IAP, a store like view controller is presented that lets the user see if they want to purchase it.  If the person has purchased the IAP, then they get to use the feature they have unlocked.

The IAP I setup only has an English version.  Is this permissible for an app that is distributed worldwide when the tab that offers the premium feature is displayed no matter what?  Or should the app be distributed only to countries where English is the primary language until I decide to localize it.  I'm just curious if it will get rejected solely for this reason, or if people who download the app in a country where English is not the primary language will be assumed to speak English and still see the IAP.

Maybe I'm over-thinking this, but I didn't want to wait through the entire review process when its documented somewhere that this will be rejected (I couldn't find it if it is).  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the localization that the store returns for the product description is based on the assigned iTunes store of the test user you are using. The device's language setting only pertains to the resources loaded locally.

Although there is definitely an option to add other languages and description from iTunes connect and it would help out if the costumers can read the description in native languages.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  Maybe let me word the question another way: since the app is distributed "worldwide," can anyone in any country see the app, or must they have english as their primary language since it is the only one supported?

Comment: They can see the app and the description would be in English as the primary. I think you can change that by adding localization later. Just looked up the docs. Although you should be fine with English. Later on when you add localization try to add the description in native languages, although it is a lengthy process and may net worth the time. Just a thought man.

Comment: Absolutely, I just didn't know if there would be an issue with the feature being hardcoded into the app as I was afraid some users might not be given the option to buy it.  But it sounds like the will, they will just see everything in english.